# how to use getopt(s) as technique for passing in argument in bash

Tags: bash, unix, shell, getopt, getopts

Can someone show me an example how to use getopts properly or any other technique that I would be able to pass in an argument? I am trying to write this in unix shell/bash. I am seeing there is getopt and getopts and not sure which is better to use. Eventually, I will build this out to add for more options.

In this case, I want to pass the filepath as input to the shell script and place a description in the case it wasn't entered correctly.

```
export TARGET_DIR="$filepath"
```

For example: (calling on the command line)

```
./mytest.sh -d /home/dev/inputfiles
```

Error msg or prompt for correct usage if running it this way:

```
./mytest.sh -d /home/dev/inputfiles/
```

Comment: you can test specifically to see if the folder has a trailing slash, whether it exists, and whether it's a folder at all - all independent of your argument parsing method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a user, I would be very annoyed with a program that gave me an error for providing a directory name with a trailing slash. You can just remove it if necessary.

A shell example with pretty complete error checking:

```
#!/bin/sh

usage () {
  echo "usage: $0 -d dir_name"
  echo any other helpful text
}

dirname=""
while getopts ":hd:" option; do
  case "$option" in
    d)  dirname="$OPTARG" ;;
    h)  # it's always useful to provide some help 
        usage
        exit 0 
        ;;
    :)  echo "Error: -$OPTARG requires an argument" 
        usage
        exit 1
        ;;
    ?)  echo "Error: unknown option -$OPTARG" 
        usage
        exit 1
        ;;
  esac
done    

if [ -z "$dirname" ]; then
  echo "Error: you must specify a directory name using -d"
  usage
  exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d "$dirname" ]; then
  echo "Error: the dir_name argument must be a directory
  exit 1
fi

# strip any trailing slash from the dir_name value
dirname="${dirname%/}"
```

For getopts documentation, look in the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins)

Comment: Thanks. At first it didnt work, but i had my getopts logic in a function instead of in the main body

Answer (score 0):

Correction to the ':)' line:

```
:)  echo "Error: -$OPTARG requires an argument"
```

because if no value got provided after the flag, then OPTARG gets the name of the flag and flag gets set to ":" which in the above sample printed:

```
Error: -: requires an argument
```

which wasn't useful info.

Same applies to:

```
\?)  echo "Error: unknown option -$OPTARG"
```

Thanks for this sample!